# React Material UI Drawer — Sliding Transition not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend, navigation-drawer

I have written a drawer for my react app

```
const Sidebar = () => {
    return (
      <Drawer
        open={burgerModalOpen}
        onClose={() => setBurgerModalOpen(false)}
      >
        <Box>
          <Navigator />
        </Box>
      </Drawer>
    );
  };
```

```
const [burgerModalOpen, setBurgerModalOpen] = React.useState(false);
```

```
return (
      <>
        <MobileSideBarContainer>
          <BurgerIconContainer onClick={_handleOpenMobileBurger}>
            <div>
              <BurgerIcon />
            </div>
          </BurgerIconContainer>
          <Sidebar />
        </MobileSideBarContainer>
      </>
    );
  }
```

The drawer just 'appears' and 'disappears' ... it's not sliding in like it does [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-drawer/)

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The sidebar returns the drawer object. Most likely on every new render there is a new drawer object created. Due to which there is [some issue](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/10587) regarding refs internally. Can you try using a variable -

```
const drawer = (
    <Drawer open={burgerModalOpen} onClose={() => setBurgerModalOpen(false)}>
      <Box>
        <Navigator />
      </Box>
    </Drawer>
  );

const Sidebar = () => {
    return drawer;
  };
```

Comment: it's still just appearing ... i read the github page and they said add       transitionDuration={{ appear: 500, enter: 500, exit: 500 }}. now the background is fading with time, but the sidebar is still just 'appearing' ... not sliding in from the left side

Comment: update: not putting it in a variable and directly placing the code into the main display return (<></>) made it work. I do not know why but it works.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had set Drawler component to conditional and when I removed conditional it worked.